# Choosing between a ductless and vented range hood for an electric stove

Tags: exhaust-fan, stove

I want to have an electrician replace our current stove-top fan for an old, electric stove. However, we have the option of getting either ductless, or one that vents outside. Installation of one that vents outside would be considerably more expensive.

I'm seeing that we typically want to vent a gas stove outside, but is there any real need for venting a small electric stove? To be clear, what I'm concerned about is the steam we produce, as we do a lot of steaming and boiling.

Would a ductless range hood suffice in protecting our home from steam damage, or would it be a better option to vent outside?

Comment: Cooking is cooking. Doesn't much matter how--it still stinks at times. Most of the exhausting range hoods I've encountered in life have been over electric stoves. This is really a matter of opinion, though.

Comment: I'm mainly concerned about the steam causing damage to our kitchen. If venting outside will avoid damage to our house then the extra cost is worth it, if it has no tangible benefit then we may not do it.

Comment: Well there you go. What's left for us to say? Isn't that a "tangible" benefit?

Comment: Well, I'm not clear about the impact that steam will have on my kitchen. I've tried Googling, but most of the results are coming from companies trying to sell me a range hood.

Comment: Do you cook fish?   Do you ever burn anything on the stove?   Do you ever sneak a smoke?

Comment: Every kitchen should have some means of effective ventilation, which doesn't necessarily have to be a range hood. Through-wall fans can be very effective. A kitchen without vents to the exterior will eventually become coated everywhere with cooking residues. Unvented ("ductless" as you call it) range hoods are next to useless. Some of them provide decent over-cooktop lighting.

Comment: Steam in a kitchen will do no more, and no less, harm than in a bathroom that sees regular steamy showers. Cheap lighting and other fixtures can become rusty/corroded quite quickly under those conditions.

Answer (score 1):

I've had both in this house - the original builder installed a recirculating hood even though it was on an outside wall.

Go for the extractor.

It's much better for stopping cooking smells and grease spreading around the house.  Washable filters aren't all that effective, and replaceable filters don't last very long at all.

If you're worried about cooking steam (I'm not, because I have a dehumidifier running nearby) then definitely get the extractor and get rid of the steam.  My old recirculating hood led to a lot of condensation on the wall above its outlet. Whether steam is worth worrying about depends on your climate and cooking style (the easiest way to reduce it is never boil uncovered, after all).

Answer (score 1):

Vented!

Vented range hoods are not meant for gas ranges any more than they are for electric ones. Their purpose is not to supply combustion air or to exhaust combustion products.  If you think you have a problem with that you should get CO detectors in your kitchen and deal with it separately.  Range hoods move far, far more air than is required for combustion.

Unvented range hoods are mostly good at making noise.  But if they are well designed and well maintained with high quality filters cleaned and changed frequently, they can remove particles of smoke, droplets of oil and other food particles given off by cooking, and by doing so they can remove some smells.  They do not remove heat or moisture from the air.  (To avoid pedantic argument about this: they can remove a tiny amount especially when they start up cold.  Ok.)

Vented hoods are much better at doing everything, and especially since you said a key purpose for you is steam, you should go with a vented one. You crack open a window while cooking, turn on the hood, and it flows air through the room replacing steam and cooking smells with fresh outside air.  This flow prevents most of the steam etc from flowing to other rooms.